# how to override Controller, Model, Views in yii2

Tags: yii2

How to override the class module in the config of my theme? I tried so impossible.

```
return [
   ...
   'modules' => [
       'shop' => [
        'class' => 'app\modules\shop\ShopModule',
           'components' => [
               'manager' => [
                   'class' => 'app\web\theme\modules\shop\Customer',
               ],
           ],
    ],
...
  ],

];
```

Comment: please explain your question more.

Comment: Example: [link](http://www.ch-webdev.de/2014/11/yii2-modul-override-controller-model-views/) Views redefined, the model fails.

Comment: than you are asking wron question.

Comment: What's not clear? I have a site on YII2. Create a folder with its own theme and configuration. The config overrides the submission of the original site. Now I need to override a class module in your theme.

Comment: Sorry, I still have absolutely no idea what you are trying to do, or what you want help with. What are you trying to override?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Overriding controllers

Sometimes you may need to override default Yii2-user controllers. It is pretty easy and takes two steps.
Step 1: Create new controller

First of all you need to create new controller under your own namespace (we’d recommend app\controllers\user) and extend it from needed Yii2-user controller.

For example, if you want to override AdminController you should `create app\controllers\user\AdminController` and extend it `from dektrium\user\controllers\AdminController:`

```
<?php

namespace app\controllers\user;

use dektrium\user\controllers\AdminController as BaseAdminController;

class AdminController extends BaseAdminController
{
    public function actionCreate()
    {
        // do your magic
    }
}
```

Step 2: Add your controller to controller map

To let Yii2-user know about your controller you should add it to controller map as follows:

```
<?php return [
    ...
    'modules' => [
        ...
        'user' => [
            'class' => 'dektrium\user\Module',
            'controllerMap' => [
                'admin' => 'app\controllers\user\AdminController'
            ],
            ...
        ],
        ...
    ],
```

For overriding view [click here](http://yii2-user.readthedocs.org/en/latest/basics/overriding-views.html)

Comment: This functional module YII2-user, in the usual YII2 is not supported.
Problem solved so, in the entry script of his theme, he added:    
    Yii::$classMap['app\modules\review\models\ModelName'] = '@app/web/theme/module/models/review/ModelName.php';